# Want to filter horizontal normals in xyz vector file (matlab) Code working but not correct

Tags: matlab, vector, normals

I have a vector dataset (Nx3) with xyz positions. I calculated the normals for all the points in my dataset.

What I want to do is filter out all horizontal normals (that is, when the y points represent a vertical feature in my data).

I have this thus far but it's only filtering out points in the x-space. I'm confused if I should be in xz space or yz space to filter out horizontal normals? Suggestions?

```
%dimension Nx3 (N variable by scene used)
normals = 'normals.csv';
P1 = csvread(normals);

%dimension Nx3 (N variable by scene used)
pts = 'pts.csv';
P0 = csvread(pts);

threshold = .5

%calculate angle between normal vectors and rotated data
ang = atan2( P0(:,2) - P1(:,2), P0(:,1) - P1(:,1) )

%filter data
filter = abs(ang) < threshold;
newNormals = P1(~filter, :);
newPts = P0(~filter,:);

dlmwrite('newpts.txt', finalPts, 'delimiter',' ')
```

Comment: finaly somebody logical indexing :) Anyway, What is P0? Its not defined. As for you only getting the x Points, When P1(1,:)=[x,y,z] and you just look at the P1(:,2) and P1(:,1), the z-Axis doesnt do anything.

Comment: AH sorry, I realized that when I ran it just now. I was rotating the data but just left it out since it wasn't working. I just edited my original post.

Comment: I've also tried different combinations of columns: ang = atan2( P0(:,1) - P1(:,1), P0(:,3) - P1(:,3) ) and the same thing happens, it crops the data in the x plane

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the y-axis points upward, it seems like you are only checking the projection of your vector on the xy-plane. If you are trying to filter all vertical vectors, then you should do the exact same check on the yz-plane as well.

```
% xy-projection
x_filter = abs(atan2(P0(:,2)-P1(:,2),P0(:,1)-P1(:,1))<threshold;
% yz-projection
z_filter = abs(atan2(P0(:,2)-P1(:,2),P0(:,3)-P1(:,3))<threshold;
% xy-projection and yz-projections are both vertical
filter = x_filter & z_filter;
```

But another check would be that `diff(x)` and `diff(z)` are both zero.

```
threshold = 1e-3;
% what is relative difference between vector's length and diff(y)?
filter = abs(1-norm(P0-P1)./(P0(:,2)-P1(:,2)))<threshold;
```

then use your filter as previously.

```
newNormals = P1(~filter, :);
newPts = P0(~filter,:);
```